# Implementing XSLT view in Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring Tools Suite 3 and I'm trying to implement XSLT view. So far I've only made this changes:

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".xsl" />
</bean>
```

**Controller.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(HttpSession session, Model model)
{
    return "home";
}
}
```

My question is how to create XML data source and pass it to XSLT? I would like to see code example.

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?49965-Document-view-Samples might help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe returning a DOMSource() with your model like below:

```
@RequestMapping 
public String overview(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("obj", new DOMSource());
return "list";
}
```

You have [an example](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?64198-XsltView-vs-AbstractXsltView-need-help&p=285253#post285253) on the [SpringSource forum](http://forum.springsource.org).

Don't forget SimpleFormController (from the example in my link, is deprecated in Spring 3.0.x, but the logic for implementing the XSL View is the same.

You could find some things very usefull in the [official docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#view-xslt).

In particular, the sections:
[17.5.1.3 Convert the model data to XML](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#view-xslt-subclassing)
[17.5.1.4. Defining the view properties](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#view-xslt-viewdefinitions)
[17.5.1.5. Document transformation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#view-xslt-transforming)

Your controller:

```
package xslt;
```

// imports omitted for brevity

```
public class HomePage extends AbstractXsltView {

protected Source createXsltSource(Map model, String rootName, HttpServletRequest
    request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Element root = document.createElement(rootName);

    List words = (List) model.get("wordList");
    for (Iterator it = words.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String nextWord = (String) it.next();
        Element wordNode = document.createElement("word");
        Text textNode = document.createTextNode(nextWord);
        wordNode.appendChild(textNode);
        root.appendChild(wordNode);
    }
    return new DOMSource(root);
}
```

Your `view.properties` file:

```
home.(class)=xslt.HomePage
home.stylesheetLocation=/WEB-INF/xsl/home.xslt
home.root=words
```

Your XSLT stylesheet file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head><title>Hello!</title></head>
            <body>
                <h1>My First Words</h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Good luck!

Added about the [Apache FOP project and XSL Transformation with Servlets](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1rc1/servlets.html):

```
private FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
private TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

public void init() throws ServletException {
    //Optionally customize the FopFactory and TransformerFactory here
}

[..]

//Setup a buffer to obtain the content length
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//Setup FOP
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);

//Setup Transformer
Source xsltSrc = new StreamSource(new File("foo-xml2fo.xsl"));
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsltSrc);

//Make sure the XSL transformation's result is piped through to FOP
Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

//Setup input
Source src = new StreamSource(new File("foo.xml"));

//Start the transformation and rendering process
transformer.transform(src, res);

//Prepare response
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(out.size());

//Send content to Browser
response.getOutputStream().write(out.toByteArray());
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Comment: But AbstractXsltView class was deprecated.

Comment: Too, lol, so try to find a not outdated way to do this... maybe with [MarshallingView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/xml/MarshallingView.html). Don't forget to add spring-oxm package to your maven dependencies, if any.

Comment: Of course, it will marshall/unmarshall any java objects you need to render, but Spring 3.1.x . If you need to print the output as XML, it could be handy to do so with the `produces` attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation. Otherwise, e.g. if you need to produce XHTML from your XLST transformation, then you should search about any implementation of XPath i.e. XALAN and write your own logic. Looking about [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/xslt.html) which seems to provide template support for Spring.

Comment: As an alternative to [Xalan](http://xalan.apache.org/), there is too [JAXP](http://jaxp.java.net/) which is a very good lib for parsing XML.

And inside the [FOP project](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1rc1/servlets.html), you have an example of XSL Transformation: see my edited response upper.

Comment: is there a possibility to access and handle model attributes (model.setAttribute()) in XsltView?

Comment: Oh in the view itself, I don't think you need that, because you can print the values of exposed model attributes with `${theModelAttributeKey}` (at least with JSPs, but something similar - if not the same - must exists with XsltView)